# debugging remote event receiver using service bus not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, pnp-powershell, remote-event-receiver

My scenario is i had a working application that i was able to debug perfectly some month back using service bus but is not working anymore. I don't have any errors and none of my breakpoints are hitting. I have seen that service bus are now using sas connection string and remote event receiver uses acs. Can someone help on this issue please.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer.

I have **attach a cloud debugger to the project** and it does the trick.